# How should I keep my git project branch up to date with master?

Tags: git, msysgit

Let's say I have a `master` branch and a `project` branch, both on our remote `origin`. Work is mainly being done in the `project` branch, but occasionally a bug fix needs to go into `master` so it can be deployed immediately. Eventually when the project is done, I want to be able to squash all the commits in project into a single commit and then merge that into `master`.

Usually with feature branches (that are not pushed to `origin`), we keep them up to date by merely rebasing with `master` and going on our merry way, but because `project` is its own branch on `origin`, I'm not sure how to keep the history the way I want it (commits from `master`, then new `project` commits, with no merge commits ideally) due to the safeguards about rewriting history on remote branches. Currently we do it by deleting the remote `project` and recreating it with the correct history, but this is definitely suboptimal.

I'm okay with rewriting history on remote `project` because this is only a team of 2 and we understand the implications and are willing to be ridiculously careful. But how do I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout project
git rebase master
git push origin +project:project
```

Now just to figure out how to correctly pull the changes on another computer!

Comment: If one goes down this road and ignores the typical advice not to rebase changes that are in a remote, then other clients can often get away with pulling the changes using:

git checkout project
git pull --rebase

See: http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Perils-of-Rebasing

Answer (score 2):

you can merge braches in git

```
git checkout project

git merge origin/master
```

That will merge any changes that master has into project, as long as they came from the same ancestor.

Comment: This is only part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to cherrypick the respective change in 'project' into 'master', so that 'master' contains the code you want.

I would then either merge 'master' back into 'project', or just keep track of the patch-id's that have been applied. (Whichever approach, do it consistently!). Personally, I think merging  'master' back into 'project' is simpler for the long term.

Comment: Getting the code from `project` into `master` isn't what I'm worried about. I thing merging `master` back into `project` instead of rebase `project` onto `master` may do what I want, though, because I'll be squashing away any merge commits anyway, but I'll have to go try it and see if it got the history the way I want it.

Comment: Consider instead the '--first-parent' option for git log and gitk rather than squashing the merges.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding feature branches I prefer rebasing them on `master`. This is especially useful for long running feature branches that may require a lot of development before getting back into `master` while `master` will evolve in parallel.

Rebasing will take your branch's change and apply them on `master`, the result will be your new branch. `master` itself will stay untouched.

You can do this like follows when your `project` branch is checked out:

```
(project) $ git rebase master
```

or explicitly:

```
(some-branch) $ git rebase master project
```

**Note:** Rebasing will rewrite your branch's history! So be careful.

Please see the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) for more information.

Comment: Yes, this is currently what we do with feature branches. My question is specifically regarding a long-running project branch that also exists on `origin`, which has its own feature branches shooting off of it.

Comment: Well, it's probably best to also rebase the "sub-branches" using `rebase --onto`.